# Divide Values by Row SUM in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI so I may have titled this wrong but I'm trying to use a SUMPRODUCT in my table but the total is incorrect.

My goal is to take the SUMPRODUCT of (Linear_Feet_Out,Hrs) / SUM(Linear_Feet_Out)

So I broke it down to try and solve the problem but am having no luck.  Slitting_Time_New is just my est field to make sure each row is calculating correctly.  So 2.000 * 226,795 = 453,589

However the results I am expecting are 2.54 in the "Slitting_Time_Avg" field total.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Slitting_Time_Avg =
VAR Numerator = [Slitting_Time_New]
VAR Denominator =
    SUM (Mfng_Analysis[Linear_Footage_Out] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( Numerator, Denominator ) )
```

But I want it to take the sum of Slitting_Time_New (a calc measure), not the 8,719,451.50

```
Slitting_Time_New = SUM(Mfng_Analysis[Hrs])*SUM(Mfng_Analysis[Linear_Footage_Out])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to evaluation context. When using the `SUM` function, DAX has no row context, unless you actively provide it in a visual table, i.e. for the Total row in your table `[Slitting_Time_New]` will evaluate

```
(2,000+2,900+0,800)x(226795+1136807+166127).
```

What you want to do, I guess, is

```
(2,0000x226795)+(2,900x1136807)+(0,800x166127)
```

In order to do that you have to provide row context. This you can do with an aggregator function, such as [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax).

```
Slitting_Time_New = 
SUMX(
    Mfng_Analysis;
    [Hrs]*[Linear_Footage_Out]
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  What do I do for the division part ?  As in to get the weighted average.

Comment: The total row of [Slitting_Time_Avg] should come out as 2.54 just by changing how you calculate [Slitting_Time_New], at least it did in my test model.